# saved jpeg viewing later

Tags: android

I am working on a application that will stores a drawn canvas as jpeg image in SD card.
The issue is when i tried to view the saved image it is loading for lot of time than other images i want the saved image to be viewed in normal time as like other images 
My code for saving an image is:

```
            View content = drawView;
            content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            content.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_LOW);
            Bitmap bitmap = content.getDrawingCache();

            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
            String file_name="Imatge"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg";
            File file = new File(path,file_name);
            FileOutputStream ostream;
            try {                   
                ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG,50, ostream);
                ostream.flush();
                ostream.close();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " :) Image saved in "+ path+"/"+file_name, 5000).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString()+"error", 5000).show();
            }
                }
```

Thanks in advance please help me!!!!

Comment: What do you mean by  it is loading for lot of time than other images?

Comment: fotos taken in android mobile are viewed in gallery in normal time but the image created by my application is taking much time to view image in gallery dont know why

Comment: did u check the file size of your Image? Maybe its too big to load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I myself find the solution , the solution is to store the image thru media store here is my code that is working correctly

```
View content = drawView;
                content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                content.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_AUTO);
                Bitmap bitmap;
                bitmap = content.getDrawingCache();             
                String file_name="MyImage"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg";

                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(Images.Media.TITLE,"MyImage");                   
                values.put(Images.Media.DESCRIPTION,"Advanced Practice");                   
                values.put(Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
                Uri url = null;

                try 
                {   
                    url = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getContentUri("external"), values);
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), bitmap,"MyImage","Advanced Practice");                     
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " :) Image saved in /sdcard/DCIM/Camera/"+file_name, 5000).show();
                } 
                catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString()+"error", 5000).show();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code saves the image as a PNG file (even though you give it the file extension .jpg). PNG files are lossless and thus much larger than JPEG file.

To fix it, save it as JPEG:

```
ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, ostream);
```

Comment: sorry not working it is also taking long time to view the saved image in sd card

Comment: @ThiruVT: Can you give us some numbers. How big is the saved image and how big are the other images (in terms of KB/MB on the SD and in terms of width and height)? And how long does your image take to load and how long do the other images take to load?

Comment: image size is not big even its size is 5 kb only this image takes 15sec to 20sec to load normal image take 2 3 secs only

Comment: What are the image's dimension (width and height)? What exactly do you mean by "load"? Do you use a viewer? Do you load it directly on the phone or from your computer? Do you use your own code to load it? (P.S: Is your keyboard broken? Your question and comments contain no punctuation and are difficult to read.)

Comment: load is time taken to view the image , i am viewing the image in my device and i didnt add any dimension to image in code :(

Comment: Your image has dimensions, e.g. it might be 400 pixels wide and 320 pixels high. So what are the dimensions of your image? And how are you viewing it? With your own code and your own app, or with what app? Please answer my questions fully if you want help.

Comment: bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 200, 300,true); i added this code to add dimension and its size is 8kb still the same problem sir , i am viewing my image from my file browser ,through  Default gallery image viewer

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11812/discussion-between-thiru-vt-and-codo)

Answer (score 0):

use as given below

```
        String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                     FileOutputStream out = null;
                     Log.e("h",""+mview.getMeasuredHeight()+" "+mview.getMeasuredWidth());
                    try {
                         out = new FileOutputStream(new File(extStorageDirectory + "/myAwesomeDrawing.jpg"));
                         mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out); 
                         out.flush(); 
                         out.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

where **mBitmap** is Gloabal variable that u have used in ur **Drawview** class  so by using this u have to skip this lines menas comment in this lines

```
  /*View content = drawView;
     content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        content.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_LOW);
        Bitmap bitmap = content.getDrawingCache();
*/
```

may it works